# Unit Testing angular $httpBackend service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got right now a project were we need to have the backend server mocked for the time being and we are using `$httpBackend` on the application `.run` feature.  I need to unit test this service that contains the `$httpBackend` as we will be having a vast amount of mocked calls to the server we will be covering. So right now this is what I have.  As a preface to my question the current setup works when I call `mockDataService.getWorkflowTask` from a controller on a simple page.

My Server replacement service:

```
angular.module('app').run(function ($httpBackend, $resource, FakeBackendService) {
    // TODO: add all necessary http intercepts.  
    $httpBackend.whenGET('JSON file').respond(function (method, url, data) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.send(null);
        return [request.status, request.response, {}];
    });
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).respond(function (method, url, data) {

        return [200, FakeBackendService.getWorkflowTasks(), {}];
    });
});
```

Here is the service for `FakeBackendService`:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var injectParams = [];

    function service(lodash) {
        var vm = this;

        var ret = {
            getWorkflowTasks: getWorkflowTasks
        };

        function getWorkflowTasks() {
            if (vm.workflowtasks.length < 1) {
                vm.workflowtasks = loadWorkflowTasks("Some JSON file");
            }
            return vm.workflowtasks;
        };

        function loadWorkflowTasks(file) {
            var workflowTasks = [];
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", file, false);
            request.send(null);

            if (request.status == 200) {
                workflowTasks = angular.fromJson(request.response);
            }
            return workflowTasks;
        };

        function init() {
            vm.workflowtasks = [];
        }

        init();

        return ret;
    }

    service.$inject = injectParams;
    angular.module('mock.FakeBackendService', []).service('FakeBackendService', service);
})();
```

So that is currently the backend server replacement mock. The following is my data handling service which contains the call to `$http.get(blah blah blah)`.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var injectParams = ['$http', '$q', 'mockConfigService', '$httpBackend'];

    function factory($http, $q, configService, $httpBackend) {
        var vm = this;

        var factory = {
            getWorkflowTask: getWorkflowTask
        };

        function getWorkflowTask(str) {
            return getResource(str);
        }

        function init() {
            // Get the URL we will be using to get data from
            vm.dataServiceURL = configService.getDataServiceURL();
        }

        function getResource(baseResource) {
            var resource = vm.dataServiceURL + baseResource;

            return $http.get(resource).then(function (response) {
                if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
                    // Got valid response
                    return $q.resolve(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    // Invalid response
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // Something went wrong
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
        }
        init();

        return factory;
    };

    factory.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('mock.dataService', []).factory('mockDataService', factory);
}());
```

Now for the Jasmine-Karma Unit test.

```
describe("HTTP Backend Mock testing", function () {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.FakeBackendService"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.configService"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.dataService"));

    it("Get the workflow task", angular.mock.inject(function (mockDataService) {
        var valid = "";

        var promise = mockDataService.getWorkflowTask('http://localhost/foo');

        promise.then(function (response) {
            valid = "Success";
        }, function (response) {
            valid = "Failure";
        });

        expect(valid).toBe("Success");
    }));
});
```

Now to the question.  So, I'll start by saying I'm new to the AngularJS world and even more so to Jasmine.  Anyways, when I debug the unit test I find that the promise's status is still 0 and I always get expected '' to be 'Success' telling my I never resolve (hopefully I'm using the right lingo) the promise from the `$http` service in `mockDataService`.  I've tried playing around with it some and tried to see if anyone has done this kind of a thing before.  I found plenty of examples where the `$httpBackend` is mocked in the test but none like what I'm attempting.  Any ideas or suggestions would be great.  Thanks.

**EDIT got a slightly working solution**

So I decided that I'd by pass the `run()` service and just do the same response in the `expectGET().respond()`.

```
describe("HTTP Backend Mock testing", function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.FakeBackendService"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.configService"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.dataService"));

    it("Get the workflow task", angular.mock.inject(function (mockDataService, $httpBackend, FakeBackendService) {
        var valid = "";
        $httpBackend.expectGET('http://server:80/api/foo').respond(200, FakeBackendService.getWorkflowTasks());
        var promise = mockDataService.getWorkflowTask('foo');


        promise.then(function (response) {
            valid = "Success";
        }, function (response) {
            valid = "Failure";
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(valid).toBe("Success");
    }));
});
```

This sort of solves my testing problem with the `run()` as the goal was to verify **1)** That the regex matching call the correct `FakeBackendService` and **2)** That `FakeBackendService` returns correct file and actually loads it.  I think I can do that by mimicking the same regex in the `expectGET`.  However, I'll leave open for a bit to see if anyone knows how to get the `run()` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The promise is not going to resolve unless you force it to do so before the test ends.  Here is one such way to do it:

```
    $httpBackend.expectGET(......).respond(200, 'abc');

    var promise = mockDataService.getWorkflowTask('http://localhost/foo');

    promise.then(function (response) {
        valid = "Success";
    }, function (response) {
        valid = "Failure";
    });

    //new code here
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(valid).toBe("Success");
```

This will force the promise to resolve and your test should pass.  You'll also need to inject the $httpBackend service into the test.

Comment: I tried and I get Error: Unexpected request: GET http://blah blah blah No more request expected

Comment: progress... now before you call mockDataService.getWorkflowTask(.....) put an $httpBackend.expectGET(blah blah blah);

Comment: I appreciate it Austin, I tried and I'm getting Error: No response defined !

Comment: $httpBackend.expectGET(blah blah blah).respond(200, {response: 'object'});

Comment: then remove the $httpbackend stuff from the test

Comment: Noob mistake, accidentally removed a piece from the karma config.  Anyways, I added the expect with the respond and flush and and I get that to resolve, oddly to failure.  If I exclude the .respond I get Error: No pending request to flush

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('mock.dataService', [])
  .service('mockDataService', function($http) {
    this.getWorkflowTask = function(url) {
      return $http.get(url)
    }
  })

describe('HTTP Backend Mock testing', function() {
  var $httpBackend
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module("mock.dataService"));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_
  }))

  it("Get the workflow task", angular.mock.inject(function(mockDataService) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost/foo').respond(200);

    var promise = mockDataService.getWorkflowTask('http://localhost/foo');

    promise.then(function(response) {
      valid = "Success";
    }, function(response) {
      valid = "Failure";
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(valid).toBe("Success");
  }));
})
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```